# Microsoft Account does not complete authentication in UWP using Azure Mobile Services

Tags: uwp, azure-mobile-services

I have a C# UWP Windows App built with Visual Studio 2017 and I'm adding Microsoft Account authentication, following the article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-users).  The app authenticates on the mobile service site within and ends up with "connecting to service" dialog hosting a page from the mobile service site saying "You have successfully signed in", but nothing happens in the app.  When I close the dialog, I get an exception that the authentication was cancelled by the user.

```
var user = await DataModel.MobileService.LoginAsync(
                    MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount, 
                    true);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I followed the tutorial you provided about [Add authentication to the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-users#add-authentication) into my UWP app to check this issue. I called the `LoginAsync` method with `uriScheme` parameter as follows:

```
var user = await App.MobileService
    .LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount, "bruceapp");
```

After user signed in, I could retrieve the user info.

Based on your code, I checked [SingleSignOnExtensions.LoginAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn268373(v=azure.10).aspx) and found the description about `useSingleSignOn` as follows:

> **useSingleSignOn**
>
> Indicates that single sign-on should be used. Single sign-on requires that the **application's Package SID be registered with the Microsoft Azure Mobile Service**, but it provides a better experience as HTTP cookies are supported so that users do not have to login in everytime the application is launched.

I searched the web and found that configure the package SID is from Azure Mobile Services that has been superseded by Azure Mobile Apps. For more details, you could refer to [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/docs/mobile-services-how-to-register-microsoft-authentication.md).

Also, I tested your code on my side and found the login window could not automatically close and the user login info could not be retrieved. Here is a git [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/issues/370) talking about the similar scenario.

Additionally, you could add your feedback at issues of [Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/issues).